# Clojure: multiple uses of the same symbol defining and calling a recursive function

Tags: recursion, clojure

I've got a recursive function (scavenged from github):

```clj
(defn delete-recursively [fname]
  (let [func (fn [func f]
               (when (.isDirectory f)
                 (doseq [f2 (.listFiles f)]
                   (func func f2)))
               (clojure.java.io/delete-file f))]
    (func func (clojure.java.io/file fname))))
```

I can't figure out this `func` thing. I need help :)

Why is it possible to use the same symbol `func` for

- the name the function is bound to,
- the name of an argument in the `fn` form,
- the called function and
- the first parameter of the call?

Or is something else going on?

Comment: When I saw this code, I had similar questions regarding the double appearance of the symbol `func`, ultimately realizing it simply involved threading `func` as an argument to facilitate recursion. Perhaps a valid question is along the lines: "Is there a clearer and more understandable way to write this code?"

Answer (score 0):

Written from my phone so I apologize.

This function seems needlessly obfuscated.

"func"is a function that delete normal files if given a file and apply a function "f" passed as parameter to all files in a directory if given a directory.

Now "func"is given to "func" as "f" parameter so it does its job recursively.

Easy :3